Spring + Thymeleaf Nested Form Backing Object Variables
I'm having null pointer errors when attempting to reference a form backing objects nested variables.
For example
        ...
        <input th:field="*{workOrder.customer.name}">
        ...


where say the customer dto (in this example we are using nested dto objects) is null results in a null pointer error.
I tried doing this
<input th:field="*{workOrder?.customer?.name}">
but then thymeleaf complains that workOrder? doesn't exist in the object as a field which is technically true but thymeleaf is confusing the null safe operator with the field name...
So then I tried
<input th:field="*{workOrder.customer} != null ? *{workOrder.customer.name} : ''">
But I am not a fan of this as its rather cumbersome to type out, looks really ugly in the html, and threw an error

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Expression "*{workOrder.customer} != null ? *{workOrder.customer.name} : ''" is not valid: only variable expressions ${...} or selection expressions *{...} are allowed in Spring field bindings

So I naively thought hey why not try nesting form backing objects and handling them as we go down the DOM
ie: The thymeleaf documentation gives an example at section 14.2
<body th:object="${order}">

  ...

  <div th:object="*{customer}">
    <p><b>Name:</b> <span th:text="*{name}">Frederic Tomato</span></p>
    ...
  </div>

  ...
</body>

…which makes that *{name} equivalent to:
<p><b>Name:</b> <span th:text="${order.customer.name}">Frederic Tomato</span></p>
Mind you this nested feature is desirable as it removes all the bloat that is present in the first half of this questions html code.

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: The expression used for object selection is *{workOrder}, which is not valid: only variable expressions (${...}) are allowed in '{th:object,data-th-object}' attributes in Spring-enabled environments.

Then I found out there is seperate documentation for Thymeleaf and Thymleaf + Spring.
I am using Thymeleaf + Spring and the Thymeleaf + Spring documentation has no mention of the fact that the content inside *{...} has to be very specific, cannot be nested and is different than standard Thymeleaf.
So after years of development, I've come to the realization that I cannot even manage a null pointer exception and am useless even with documentation.
Any suggestions?

This is a problem I would solve on the backing object... if you want to have a form with *{workOrder.customer.name} then your WorkOrder object should have an empty Customer even if there are none in the database.

While yes this is technically a solution it comes with additional repercussions that prevent me from implementing it. Specifically, I am using mapstruct to convert to and from entity to dto. With non null dto's comes non null empty entities leading to invalid data in the database. Yes I can implement functionality for form backing dto's to only be the ones to have concrete child fields but this is hardly a solution for something that should be simple to resolve. Thymeleaf has ? operator why ins't that implemented for *{...} when using thymeleaf and spring?

Then I think the only other option here is to stop using th:field and manually set the name and value of your inputs.  As long as the name matches what th:field would generate, I think it might bind correctly even if the objects are null?
